# Posting inside the page in another form action?

Tags: php

I am currenty having a thesis project which is the voting system, and my problem is how can I count the vote if I click on the radio button after I click the next button how to updates the votes?. And  guys is it possible that in my php page I can save my data but the form action is not the saving part I mean like this

I have a form codes:
//preview page is the page where I can see all tha candidates that I have choose.

```
   <form id="msform" action="preview.php" method="POST">
    <?php
            $resultasa = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candposition");
            $resultasa->execute();
                for($i=0; $rowasa = $resultasa->fetch(); $i++){
                        $exrxrxrx=$rowasa['pos_name'];
                        if($exrxrxrx=='President'){
                ?>  

                <fieldset>
                        <table>
                        <tr><td><h2 class="fs-title"><?php echo $rowasa['pos_name'] ?></h2></td>
                        <td><input  name="<?php echo $rowasa['pos_name'] ?>" type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
                        </tr>

                <?php

                        $YearNow=Date('Y');
                        $dsds=$rowasa['posid'];
                        $results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates,student,school_year,partylist where student.idno = candidates.idno AND school_year.syearid = candidates.syearid AND posid =:a AND candidates.partyid = partylist.partyid AND  school_year.from_year like $YearNow  ");

                $results->bindParam(':a', $dsds);
                $results->execute();

                for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){
        ?>



   <td><img src="admin/candidates/images/<?php echo $rows['image']; ?>" height="160px;" width="155px;"></td>

                    <td><br>
                    <div style="text-align:center">
                    <input name="pres" style="margin-left:-19px;" type="radio"   value="<?php echo $rows['candid'] . "-" ."&nbsp".  $rows['lastname']. "&nbsp". $rows['firstname'] ?>"> <?php echo $rows['lastname'] ?>,
                        <?php  echo $rows['firstname'] ?>

                    - <?php 

                            echo $rows['party_name']?>

                    <?php
```

//I think this part will be having an update like

```
    $sql = "UPDATE candidates
                    SET votes=votes+?
                    WHERE candid=? ";

$q = $db->prepare($sql);
                }
            ?>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: and did you "execute" the query?

Comment: yes like $q = $db->prepare($sql);
     $q->execute(array($sql));

Comment: don't know how to update the counting of votes with their value

Comment: Start with the manual http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements you're missing something.